# Running unit test for windows phone library solution

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone

I'm using **Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone, update 4**

I've created solution with project type **Windows Phone Class Library** targeting **Windows Phone 7.1** platform.

After some coding done I've figured out that it would be nice to add some tests to the solution. So I added **Windows Phone Unit Test App** to the solution and created some bogus test that should failed:

```
[TestClass]
public class BogusTester
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void BogusTest()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(true, false);
    }
}
```

I've opened `Test Explorer` windows where I can see my test, but it is grayed out and when i hit `Run All` nothing happens (i.e. project is building but test does not return any value)

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT
Also I've found output of tests:

```
Failed to import IDeployService. Cannot proceed with xap deployment. This failure can be observed if the component model cache (typically located in %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\[version]\ComponentModelCache) is not up-to-date.  To come out of this error, close all instances of visual studio, delete the component model cache folder and try again.
Unit tests in source D:\projekty\PhoneApp3\TestApp1\Bin\x86\Debug\TestApp1.dll cannot be run. Please create a Windows Store or Windows Phone Unit Test project.
```

I've deleted ComponentModelCache for my user, but this does not help, also I can't find any resource about this error on the Internet

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this note:
"You can only author unit tests for apps that target Windows Phone 8. Windows Phone 7, 7.5, 7.8 are not supported."
from - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/01/31/windows-phone-unit-tests-in-visual-studio-2012-update-2.aspx

3rd point under: FAQs and Known Issues

HTH.

Comment: That is actually not true, as I can easly import WP7 library in WP8 project (and I do it successfully under VS exp 2013)